# File Not Found with a local repository

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository, localrepository

I have a repository on my hard disk with the following `sources.list` configuration:

```
deb "file:///media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:///media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:///media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:///media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:///media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

when I execute `ls -lh /media/miguel/My\ Passport/xenial-repo`, I get:

```
total 16K
drwxrwxrwx 1 miguel miguel 4,0K mar 15 12:57 dists
drwxrwxrwx 1 miguel miguel    0 mar 15 13:47 pool
-rwxrwxrwx 1 miguel miguel  12K jun  4 06:01 Problema con repositodio.odt
drwxrwxrwx 1 miguel miguel    0 mar 15 16:03 project
```

when I execute `sudo apt-get update` I get:

```
miguel@Violette:~$ sudo apt-get update
Des:1 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Des:1 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Des:2 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Des:3 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Des:2 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Des:3 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Des:4 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed InRelease [253 kB]
Des:4 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed InRelease [253 kB]
Des:5 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Des:5 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Des:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages [1196 kB]
Ign:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages
Des:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages [8684 B]
Ign:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Des:8 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/universe i386 Packages [7512 kB]
Ign:8 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/universe i386 Packages
Des:9 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages [140 kB]
Ign:9 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages [1196 kB]
Des:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages [8684 B]
Ign:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Des:8 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/universe i386 Packages [7512 kB]
Ign:8 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/universe i386 Packages
Des:9 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages [140 kB]
Ign:9 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages [1552 kB]
Ign:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages
Des:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages [14,5 kB]
Ign:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Des:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [4660 B]
Ign:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Des:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [2508 B]
Ign:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Des:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [484 kB]
Ign:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Des:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7164 B]
Ign:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Des:14 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [426 kB]
Ign:14 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Des:15 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6876 B]
Ign:15 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:8 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/universe i386 Packages [9804 kB]
Ign:8 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/universe i386 Packages
Des:9 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages [172 kB]
Ign:9 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages [7188 kB]
Err:6 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages
  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
Des:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages [128 kB]
Ign:7 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Des:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [4660 B]
Ign:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Des:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [2508 B]
Ign:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Des:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [484 kB]
Ign:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Des:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7164 B]
Ign:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Des:14 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [426 kB]
Ign:14 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Des:15 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6876 B]
Ign:15 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages [108 kB]
Ign:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
Des:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages [52,3 kB]
Ign:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Des:18 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [1024 B]
Ign:18 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages [223 kB]
Ign:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Des:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [6804 B]
Ign:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Des:21 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [86,7 kB]
Ign:21 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Des:22 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2912 B]
Ign:22 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [4908 B]
Ign:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Des:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [2566 B]
Ign:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Des:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [618 kB]
Ign:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Des:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [12,4 kB]
Ign:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Des:14 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [538 kB]
Ign:14 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Des:15 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [7535 B]
Ign:15 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages [108 kB]
Ign:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
Des:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages [52,3 kB]
Ign:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Des:18 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [1024 B]
Ign:18 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages [223 kB]
Ign:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Des:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [6804 B]
Ign:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Des:21 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [86,7 kB]
Ign:21 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Des:22 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2912 B]
Ign:22 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [18,5 kB]
Err:10 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
Des:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [8664 B]
Ign:11 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Des:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [3063 kB]
Err:12 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
Des:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [98,9 kB]
Ign:13 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Des:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages [136 kB]
Ign:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
Des:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages [61,8 kB]
Ign:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Des:18 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [957 B]
Ign:18 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages [278 kB]
Ign:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Des:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [12,0 kB]
Ign:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Des:21 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [106 kB]
Ign:21 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Des:22 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3124 B]
Ign:22 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages [727 kB]
Err:16 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
Des:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages [269 kB]
Ign:17 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Des:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages [1400 kB]
Err:19 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/main i386 Packages
  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
Des:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [97,2 kB]
Ign:20 file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
N: No se podrán ignorar los privilegios para descargar mientras no se pueda acceder a «/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/InRelease» con el usuario «_apt». - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permiso denegado)
E: Fallo al obtener file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
E: Fallo al obtener file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
E: Fallo al obtener file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
E: Fallo al obtener file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
E: Fallo al obtener file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Fichero no encontrado - /media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

and at the end I can't install many programs from the repo. There is no difference between "file:///media.." or "file:/media..."

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `file:///path/to/repo`:

```
deb "file:///media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
...
```

It should be only `file:/path/to/repo`, in your case:

```
deb "file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb "file:/media/miguel/My Passport/xenial-repo" xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

For more information about about it, [How to create personal repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal#Sources.list).

Comment: I tried that and with the same results, thats no the answer that I need :'( Someone told me that the problem is with the permission buy I don't know what to do. Again, sorry by my english

Comment: Do you get the same error as you got before after editing the source.list file? In any case, please edit your question with the output of `ls -lh /media/miguel/My\ Passport/xenial-repo`.

Comment: Yes M. Becerra I get the same error as before after editing the sources.list file. I edit my question with the output, hope to somebody for a good answer. Thank you for pay me attention, and again, sorry by my english.